# EOPL procedure representation

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I have some difficulties understanding procedure representation(section 2.2.3) in Chapter 2 of *Essentials of Programming Languages* (Friedman, Wand).

First of all, why is "having exactly one observer" important for procedure representation?

Secondly, the author gives a recipe of deriving procedure representation. Does this recipe means that we can derive procedure representation fully mechanically without any thoughts?
I tried to follow the recipe to solve the exercise 2.12(Implementing a stack datatype using procedure representation), but I find it very difficult to get the solution by only relying on the recipe.

Even after I get a procedure representation of stack, I have no clue that how I can follow the same approach to implement procedure representations for other datatypes. For me, I don't even know whether it's possible to implement a procedure representation for certain datatypes before trying.